# Fast aggregation using dplyr - better way?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data frame where I have a grouping variable and then lots of other variable columns. I want to calculate the mean of each variable by group - but I want to take account of the proportion of missing data. If there is >75% of the data then calculate the mean, if not return `NA`.

My actual data has many more columns than the test data below. This approach seems to be pretty quick. My question is whether there is a quicker way?

```
# number of groups
n <- 100000
dat <- data.frame(grp = factor(rep(1:n, each = 10)),
              var1 = rep(c(1:8, NA, NA), times = n),
              var2 = rep(c(1:7, NA, NA, NA), times = n)
              )

# summarise by group, calculate mean if enough data
res <- dat %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(ifelse(length(na.omit(.)) / length(.) > 0.75, 
                         mean(., na.rm = TRUE), NA)))
```

Thanks

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option that is almost 5x faster:

```
system.time(
  res0 <- dat %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarise_each(
      funs(
        ifelse(
          length(na.omit(.)) / length(.) > 0.75, 
          mean(., na.rm = TRUE), NA)
      ) )
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   7.27    0.00    7.29 
system.time(
  res1 <- dat %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarise_each(
      funs(
        if(sum(is.na(.)) / length(.) < 0.25) mean(., na.rm=TRUE) 
        else NA
    ) )
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.59    0.00    1.60 
all.equal(res0, res1)
#  [1] TRUE
```

And an extra 2x speed increase with `data.table`:

```
system.time(
  res2 <- setDT(dat)[, 
    lapply(
      .SD, 
      function(x) 
        if(sum(is.na(x)) / .N < 0.25) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA
    ), 
  by=grp]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.76    0.00    0.76 
all.equal(res0, setDF(res2))
#  [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great - just what I want and even better with my own 'real' data with many more columns. Thanks!

Comment: `mean(is.na(.)) < 0.25` might be even faster